# pppd argument for CHAP authentication

Tags: authentication, pppd

I am trying pppd using serial port between an embedded device and a PC.

i had set the /etc/ppp/chap-secrets file with username and password

when i run the command pppd auth  i get the below output 
pppd: The remote system is required to authenticate itself
pppd: but I couldn't find any suitable secret (password) for it to use to do so.

what is the command line argument to use for setting the connection using CHAP authentication ?

thanks for the help,
Dino

Answer (score 1):

we need to supply require-chap in the argument

require-chap
              Require  the  peer  to authenticate itself using CHAP [Challenge
              Handshake Authentication Protocol] authentication.